# Research on pedestrian trajectories' interaction with camera placement

Tags: privacy, research, surveillance

I'm looking for empirical research on whether pedestrian walking trajectories are affected by areas under video surveillance. Maybe this would depend on the interval after a camera is prominently installed; maybe it will vary with the environment that the camera is placed in. I don't know---I haven't found much on this in my literature searches, so I thought I'd ask the community. I'd also be interested in anything related to other forms of sensors beyond cameras.

Comment: I'm voting to leave this open. I think it's on-topic as it's about research into surveillance, which is on-topic here. That said, you probably won't get an answer since it's a very specific question, and this site generally focuses on computer and network security.

Comment: I've got some wild guess if you want!  My wild guess is: the vast majority of pedestrians don't notice such things, and don't care if they do

Comment: You are supposing that 1) pedestrians know there are cameras nearby 2) the cameras are visible